# Current through Circular Circuit as a Function of Theta

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

I am struggling with this question. I know this question was already posted on the site but there was no clear answer.

[image]

So far, I have tried visualizing the circuit as $4$ resistors connected in parallel ($2$ resistors in $2$ branches) with a wire connecting the $2$ branches. Then these resistors would have resistance proportional to the length of wire they represent. I didn't know what to do after this step. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: is radius of circle, cross section area , resistivity of wire given?

Comment: No it cancels out for sure.

Comment: look at symmetry of question

Answer (score 0):

1. You need 5 resistors. The circuit is connected from A to B with the same type of wire, which has resistance.
2. Let's call the start and end S and E, you have five different current $I_{SA}, I_{SB},I_{AB},I_{AE},I_{BE}$. You need to find out what $I_{AB}$ is.
3. At any junction of three wires in the circuit, no charge will pile up, so the current flowing in must be the same as current flowing out. (This is called Kirchhoff's current law).

I think you can take it from here, good luck!